For applying to a STEM research position at a U.S. research university, should a resume include a photo?
I am currently applying to a STEM research position at an American research university (as an undergraduate student at that university), and was wondering what people's opinions on this site were as to whether it was advisable to attach a photo or not. I was thinking of attaching a certain photo which looked very good, but a friend said attaching the image would be "too edgy".

Photos on resumes is not a thing in the US.

@Trunk - I look at hundreds of resumes a year, ranging from student interns to experienced staff. The number of resumes that I see with a photo I can count on one hand every year, and then every single one is from someone from somewhere else where having a photo is required. No, it is not common, normal, or expected.

My kids are in that age range. They would never put a photograph on their resume. It just is not expected (or normal) in the US. There are countries where it is expected if not required. Not the US.

No.
I recommend that you never attach a photo to a resume in the US.
The US has a variety of nondiscrimination laws, for example saying that it is illegal to discriminate based on age, race, gender, or skin color, among other factors. If an employer discriminated in hiring decisions, based on the sort of things you can tell from a photo, then they could face legal consequences.
For this reason, employers will not (or should not anyway!) ask for photos.
As an applicant, it's not your responsibility to know this, and it almost certainly wouldn't be held against you -- but including a photo would stand out as being a little bit strange or unaware, and I suggest avoiding it.

it almost certainly wouldn't be held against you... - Yes, at least it math I see this from time to time from foreign applicants, and I just interpret as a cultural difference.  It is true there is some bias once you see photos, but if I'm interested in the candidate I will look at their webpage which often has photos anyway.

Some employers explicitly state that applications (CVs, resumes, etc.) that include a photograph will be disqualified without consideration.  Be sure to read the whole announcement!

I strongly recommend to any early-career academic researcher these days (at least in STEM in the US) to set up a personal web page where you can include any sort of information about yourself that you want others to see - publications, research-adjacent hobbies and activities, etc. Many people who are seriously considering you for job applications will google you and look at your web page. If you include a link to your web page at the top of your CV or résumé (which is a very normal thing to do) that makes it even more likely that people looking at your CV will look at the web page.
If you want to include a photo of yourself in your home page, who could object to that? Having such a photo is also very normal and accepted. I have a photo of myself up on my own home page, and most people I know do. We do this not to brag about how good-looking we are but because it's nice to feel like you are a part of a community of human beings.
Do not include a photo of yourself in your résumé, for reasons that other people have explained.
While the personal web page "hack" I described above gives you an opportunity to share information about how you look if that is something you wish to do, I do think statements like "I was thinking of attaching a certain photo which looked very good" reflect a somewhat unhealthy mindset. No one in STEM academia cares about your (presumably) good looks. And many people would actively take offense at the idea that you think you can gain some advantage in the job market by touting your physical looks, or any ethnic, racial, or gender characteristics that are evident from how you look. So please be careful about making such statements that may seem innocuous to you but give away the wrong idea. (E.g., when you put the link to your home page on your CV, don't write something like "photo included" next to the link...)
Good luck with your job applications! I hope you succeed, and that your success will be due to your excellence as a researcher rather than irrelevant factors. And if you ever apply for modeling jobs (fashion modeling, not scientific modeling that is) then do include some photos of yourself.

There is no reason to do so, and decisions won't be made on "how you look". I'd suggest sticking to things actually relevant to the position you are applying for.
I'm sure it is done, but is uncommon enough that it might be a bit off-putting for some. Nearly everyone in the decision process will ignore it.

Decisions shouldn't be made on how you look, but it could happen.

Only jobs in the US or probably anywhere else where a photo is useful in a  resumé would be for acting or modeling. For everything else it would just be giving them something to use to discriminant with even if this would be illegal in most case.
